# Почему в 2й переменной ()?

Tags: ruby

```
def to_s                  
   "#{@name} (#{@age})"
end
```

Comment: (c) https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby

Comment: Вас интересует, почему `#{@age}` взято в скобки?

Comment: Потому что, эм, так захотел автор программы. Читайте дальше, около `puts group.sort.reverse` тема скобок раскрывается.

Comment: Да, почему #{@age} в ()?

Comment: Потому что автор захотел выводить строки вида `"Имя (возраст)"`.

Comment: @Nofate, наверное стоит этот комментарий сделать ответом :)

Comment: @Grundy, наверное, вопрос стоит закрыть как *too opinionated*

Comment: @Nofate, а есть какие-то другие варианты для спора? :)

Answer (score 3):

Потому что автор захотел выводить строки вида "Имя (возраст)". – (c)Nofate